# How do I show the current folder name at the top of the Outlook Explorer window, like in previous versions of Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-365

Recently, my work changed from Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016 to Microsoft 365 Apps. One thing I noticed with this change is that the current folder you have open in Outlook no longer displays at the top of the Outlook window.

For example, here's what I see in Outlook 2016:

[image]

Notice how how the folder (**Application Testing**) displays at the top.

Now with Outlook 365, I have the huge search bar at the top, but don't see the current folder:

[image]

Is there a way to re-enable this feature? Or is there somewhere else I can quickly see the current folder? I can always click **Folder Properties** from the *Folder* tab, but that's not nearly as convenient.

I suppose I could also keep the sidebar open/pinned, but I'm used to keeping it collapsed to maximize space for my list of emails and reading pane.

Comment: Drag your favorite folder to the top (favorites section) of the Outlook Folder Tree. This works.

Comment: @John: This has nothing to do with my favorites. I just want to see what folder I'm currently in by looking at the top of the Outlook window.

Comment: Once you have sorted the list then, you can see if moving a folder to the top of the list turns sort off temporarily.

Comment: @John: I think we're talking past each other. In previous versions of Outlook, when you opened a specific folder in Outlook (e.g. "Bob's Emails" under your Inbox), you would see the name of that folder at the top of the window in the Title Bar.

Comment: I understand but that changed in Outlook 365.  I have adapted to a sorted list.

Answer (score 0):

As @John alluded to in the comments, having the current folder in the Title Bar is no longer an option with new versions of Outlook, at least Outlook 365. I posted this same question at [answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/how-do-i-show-the-current-folder-name-at-the-top/d4162d88-de25-4d81-b14e-1412c698cc59?messageId=38213522-026e-45c1-b5bc-c8cb622fbaee), and was told as such.

Alternatives (which aren't great) include the following:

- You can click Folder Properties to see what folder you're currently in. Of course, this necessitates going to the Folders tab and clicking a button.
- You can also keep the Folder Pane open, which will show the current folder as active. This necessitates keeping the Folder Pane open (which, for people like me who like to keep it collapsed, isn't great). Also, if you're scrolling in the Folder Pane, you can lose track of the active folder.
- You can update your Mail Item view to display the item's folder as a new column. This is my current solution.

Also, if your window settings are set to *not* combine taskbars, then the Outlook icon in your task bar will display the active folder:

[image]

There is a [suggestion](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/23111bc4-d3fa-ec11-a81b-6045bd864d4f) on the Microsoft Feedback Portal where you can vote to have it added back.

Answer (score 0):

Drove me nuts too.
Monitoring a few Inboxes and sometimes a few Sent folders as well. Not exactly what you wanted but now I can see instantly which folder I'm working in ...
All items inside my work Inbox & Sent items are now blue, personal are green, and another employee or two's emails are maroon, purple, etc.

I went to Current View at the top
--> View settings
--> Conditional formatting
--> Add
--> change font colour & Condition
--> advanced
--> Field
--> All Mail fields
--> whatever

Maybe untick the top rule (Unread messages)
Still toying with it ...

Answer (score 0):

Right click 'Folder Properties', then choose, 'Add to Quick Access Toolbar'. Now it's always one click away instead of two.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1179042)